# Circular progress bar with a gap between progress and empty arcs

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

Need to show a determinate circular progress view with a white space between progress and empty arcs as shown in the image.

[image: [1]: https://ibb.co/fOY49Q]

Please do help

Comment: did you find the solution? If yes, please help me with that.

Comment: Implementing custom view would be the solution if there are still no libraries, at the time I ended up implementing without gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this library https://github.com/jakob-grabner/Circle-Progress-View. I think this may help you in solving your problem!